# getResponse Header content-length returns null

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

There is an ajax js function which send request & get response and it often get successful but i smell somthing messy when i checked using firbug. please take a look.
***when request success:*** `ajaxRequest.getResponseHeader('content-Length'); returns null`
But in actual the `content-length` is in digits.   following is the firbug console output

```
HeadersResponseXML

Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type    text/xml
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Date    Thu, 15 Sep 2011 07:23:36 GMT
```

***when request failed :***   it returns 0 (zero),and it's correct.
    `Headers

    Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1

    Content-Length  0

    Date    Thu, 15 Sep 2011 07:23:53 GMT`

I don't see any content-length in response header when it succeed why? please compare success & failure firebug console output. How can I get actual content-length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) of the `doGet()` (or `doPost()`) method of `HttpServlet`:

> ...
>
> Where possible, set the `Content-Length` header (with the `ServletResponse.setContentLength(int)` method), to allow the servlet container to use a persistent connection to return its response to the client, improving performance. The content length is automatically set if the entire response fits inside the response buffer.
>
> When using HTTP 1.1 chunked encoding (which means that the response has a `Transfer-Encoding` header), do not set the `Content-Length` header.
>
> ...

In other words, if you do not set the content length **yourself** inside your servlet and the response body is larger than the default response buffer size (often 2KB, configureable in server settings), then the servlet will send it using chunked encoding (technically, to prevent memory problems if it had to buffer large responses entirely in memory before being able to set the content length).

If you really need the content length in the response header for some reason, then you need to buffer the entire response body yourself before writing. E.g.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(someXml);
// ...

response.setContentType("text/xml");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setContentLength(builder.length());
response.getWriter().write(builder.toString());
```

You only need to keep in mind that this can be a potential memory hog whenever the response body is extraordinary large.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for the clarification in details. I understand memory does always matter that's why i didn't want to explicitly add into response header. responseText or responseXML is best way to ignore such issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the content length is not included in the header, you simply can't get it (without reading the entire response).

The content length header is optional. You can send a stream as response where the length is not known beforehand.

Comment: Yes, this is what i tried to explain but wanted to know is there anyway to publish the content length in header either success or failure.

Comment: @user744587: The content length is usually included if it's known. For the length to be known, the entire response has to be present when the response is started. Whatever you are using to send the response, there might be a setting to enable output buffering, so that the response is stored in a buffer until it is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is an HTTP/1.1 request. You can get the actual content-length by following the HTTP 1.1 specification's rules. If chunked encoding was specified, follow the rules for chunked encoding. If there's a Content-Length header, that will tell you the content length. Otherwise, the content is finished when the connection drops (and one side or the other must include a "Connection: close" header).

If you really got a "Content-length: 0" header, then there is no content.

Comment: thanks David, does it always returns content-length 0 when there is no content OR is there any possibility to return null instead of 0.

Comment: The [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) says that a 'Content-Length' header, if present, must consist of 1 or more digits. See also section [4.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4), particularly rule 3.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the first paragraph of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding.  You don't see the content length when using chunked Transfer Encoding.  If you would prefer a Content-Length header, then you'll need to figure out how to not use chunked Transfer Encoding, which I suspect is an Apache Coyote question.

Reading http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/config/coyote.html, it looks like you'll need to figure out how to get your AJAX requests to be HTTP/1.0.

What do you need this for anyway?  Can't you just use responseText.length?

Comment: THanks Lee, this is somehow related with Apache Coyote. BTW i can  get the content-length by streaming at server side and add into response but i wanted to get it from header without any streaming at server side. BTW i tried by using `(ajaxRequest.responseText).length' and it returns `undefined`

Comment: `if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
    if (ajaxRequest.status == 200){ ... }`

Answer (score 0):

In your response headers:

```
Transfer-Encoding:   chunked
```

This an answer why `Content-Length` header is not found in response.