# any way to get file size from url without downloading it using google app script.?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Actually I don't know how can I make a head request and read content-length.
I tried to write this function:

```
function getfilesize(url) {
  var msg = '';
  var response;

  try {
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      // muteHttpExceptions: true,
      // validateHttpsCertificates: false,
      followRedirects: true  // Default is true anyway.
    });
catch(e) {
    return e.toString();
  }

var headers = response.getHeaders();
      var content_length = NaN;
      for (var key in headers) {
        if (key.toLowerCase() == 'Content-Length'.toLowerCase()) {
          content_length = parseInt(headers[key], 10);
          break;
        }

      }
return content length;
}
```

but it returns a value of  `1.81619173E8` for `173mb` in `60 sec`.
**Can anyone suggest another way of doing it faster
with google apps script?**

Comment: Maybe make a head request?

Comment: how? to do this.

Comment: I have no idea what `UrlFetchApp.fetch` is so I have no clue how to alter it to change the method to a HEAD.

Comment: There has been a feature request for `UrlFetchApp` calls with method=HEAD since 2014. The issue was assigned to someone in 2017. If we're lucky, the feature will be implemented by 2020. :-) https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36762291

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is probably about correct. That `1.81619173E8` is 1816191730 bytes, which is 173MB. `Content-Length` is always in bytes.

To convert it to MB, just divide by 1024 twice (once puts it in KB, once more for MB).

```
content_length = parseInt(headers[key], 10) / 1024 / 1024;
```

For changing the request type, it looks like `fetch()` won't accept `HEAD` directly, but you can use the `X-HTTP-Method` header to override it:

```
response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'HEAD'},
  followRedirects: true  // Default is true anyway.
});
```

That should get it to use HEAD instead of GET.

Comment: yeah it is correct but, it is taking a lot of time, Any way to do it faster

Comment: @ShubhamSoni you are fetching the whole file ...just make a HEAD request for the headers

Comment: @ charlietfl can you provide me the code to do that? i am unable to do it using google app script?

Comment: @samanime yeah your methord will convert it into mb but i want to do it faster. edit :- yeah i see it now thanks i gonna try it

Comment: @samanime it gave me error "Missing } after property list" you forgot a comma by the way thanks brother.

Comment: Updated. Thanks.

Comment: The `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header is ignored by most servers / webapps. Only works  if the server is configured correctly, which may be pretty hard to do. See for example https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPUTOrDELETENotAllowedUseXHTTPMethodOverrideForYourRESTServiceWithASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think its taking a long time because you are actually downloading the content.

I found that for my circumstance, I was able to use the `Range` header to request 0 bytes and then inspect the response headers which held the file size:

```
var params = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Range: "bytes=0-0",
    },
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileUrl,params);
  var headers = response.getHeaders();
  var fileSizeString = headers['Content-Range']
  var fileSize = +headers['Content-Range'].split("/")[1];
```

The response headers had `Content-Range=bytes 0-0/139046553` as a value that I could then use to convert to an integer (139046553) number of bytes.

Comment: Works sometimes. But `Content-Range` can also be absent, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427407/getresponse-header-content-length-returns-null.